# NCAA Football Coach Salary Data

Tags: sports, football

Is there anywhere I can find historical data‚ say over the last 30 years, on NCAA football coach salaries? Charles Clotfelter seems to have this, at least for some schools: https://twitter.com/rjisungpark/status/1133536944003137536

See also https://sports.usatoday.com/ncaa/salaries/ for 2018 only.